# C# WatiN Firefox - Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, vps, watin

I'm trying to launch a web bot developed with WatiN (via Firefox).
It launches and works perfectly on my computer (even without launching it as admin), however when I launch it from my VPS (where I'm not admin), Firefox and my application immediatly crash.

The console shows (I translated it from french) :

> Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>        to System.Net.Sockets.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>        to System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>        to System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>        to WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxClientPort.ReadResponse(Boolean resultExpected, Boolean checkForErrors)
>        to WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxClientPort.WaitForConnectionEstablished()
>        to WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxClientPort.Connect(String url, Boolean createNewFirefoxInstance)
>        to WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.FireFoxClientPort.Connect(String url)
>        to WatiN.Core.Native.Mozilla.CreateFireFoxInstance(String url)
>        to MyTranslationAutomation.MyTranslation..ctor(MyConsole& console)
>        to Program.Actions.Main()

Console:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are not having a firewall issue on the machine were you are deploying your solution? That error is not watin related at all (or at least it doesn't look like). The error that you are getting means that the machine is there but the service is not responding (for some reason), in fact you can read the stack trace pointing to the Read() and ReadResponse() method being part of it.

Comment: That's what I thought, however as I mentioned I'm not an admin on this computer, so is there a way to bypass the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked when I install a new version of the FireFox's JSSH plugin, found with SWAT: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ulti-swat/files/